# ArcGIS Pro Arcade expression to Maintain line-to-point connectivity

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, expression, arcade, water

A customer was using a geometric network to maintain connectivity between lines and points. Now they are using ArcGIS Pro, which does not support geometric networks.

They cannot use the Utility Network since they don't have an ArcGIS Enterprise license.

We are trying to handle connectivity issues with Arcade expressions in attribute rules.

Using this approach, when we move a point feature, is there a way to make the point that's connected to it move also - the same way it does in a geometric network?